# How to interrogate multiple tables with different structure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Sql-Server 2016 in a C# application.

Let's say I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_A
(
    UserID NVARCHAR2(15),
    FullName NVARCHAR2(25),
    Available NUMBER(1),
    MachineID NVARCHAR2(20),
    myDate date
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Table_B
(
    UserID NVARCHAR2(15),
    FullName NVARCHAR2(25),
    Team NVARCHAR2(15),
    MachineID NVARCHAR2(20),
    Stuff NUMBER(2)
);
```

I want to perform a global select so that I will get as result data from both tables, somehow concatenated and of course, when a column does not exist in one of the tables, that column to be automatically populated with NULL, and if a column exists on both tables the results must be merged in a single column.

The first solution that pops-up is a UNION with NULL aliases for the missing columns, sure. The problem is that at runtime I will not be able to know in advance which tables are interrogated so that I could anticipate the column names. I need a more general solution.

The expected result from the two tables must look like this:

```
user_Table_A; fullName_Table_A;  1;   machineID_Table_A; 12-JUN-18; NULL; 10;
user_Table_B; fullName_Table_B;      NULL; machineID_Table_B; NULL; team_Table_B; 20;
```

The data for the two tables is inserted with the following commands:

```
INSERT INTO Table_A VALUES ('user_Table_A', 'fullName_Table_A', 1, 'machineID_Table_A', TO_DATE('12-06-2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));

INSERT INTO Table_B VALUES ('user_Table_B', 'fullName_Table_B', 'team_Table_B', 'machineID_Table_B', 20);
```

Comment: tag the RDBMS  you're really using (is that sql server or oracle?) More, this seems like a simple join operation...

Comment: Why do you have two such similar tables?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, B3S. I am testing my operations in Oracle SQL Developer, 'cause I do not own Sql Server Management Studio. But, as I was saying, I am looking for a solution to be integrated in C#, so SQL-Server is the focus here. As for the other remark, please explain the join operation. I'm newbie at this for now. :(

Comment: jarlh, I made them similar so that my question would be more illustrative. My real tables aren't that alike. Thank you!

Comment: what is the `12-JUN-18` in your expected output? Can you add the example data you're using for both tables ?

Comment: It's just a date, doesn't matter. I just wanted to put in light the fact that the columns are different. I have updated the post with the data corresponding to the two tables.

Comment: Sorry buddy but your question still doesnt look completely clear: format your output properly. What does the `10` stands for? (last value of first row in expected output). Please try formatting it as table with headers...

Comment: It is a value for the 'Stuff" (number) column. If you run the insert for table B you will see that there is some sense in it. You are right, a table would look better, but I don't know how to format with headers here, on stack.

Comment: On a different note, you say: "at runtime ill not be able to know which tables are interrogated", here comes a problem, you should know where you're doing your query. you will NEED this information in order to make your logic work. You should get it from a parameter, a user input, a local variable anything but you cant query your db without knowing which table are u asking data.

Comment: Ahm. I see. I may be doing in advance a simple select from both tables that will come to interrogation at runtime and save the column names in a list somewhere. After that an outer join may work, like you also said, hmm.

Comment: what i see here is a parametrized query, to do in your code: you need to retrieve somehow the tables you're querying, the column list of each table (in sql server you can get em from `exec sp_columns [tablename]`) then build your query based on variables you populated

Comment: Didn't know about exec sp_columns, thank you. At least now I have something to start from. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. I havent have time to completely tweak it, so there can be something the order of the columns. But perhaps it can get you started:

You also write that you use Oracle - Im not sure what you wanted, but this is in pure sql-server version.

**SQL:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
  /*Then it exists*/
  DROP TABLE #temp;
  GO
DECLARE @SQLList nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @SQLList2 nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

with table_a as (
select column_name  as Table_aColumnName,ORDINAL_POSITION from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   
where TABLE_NAME  = 'table_a'
)

,
table_b as (
select column_name as Table_bColumnName,ORDINAL_POSITION from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   
where TABLE_NAME  = 'table_b'

)
,preresult as (
select case when Table_aColumnName IS null then 'NULL as ' + Table_bColumnName else Table_aColumnName end as Table_a_ColumnName,case when Table_bColumnName IS null then 'NULL as ' +Table_aColumnName else Table_bColumnName end as Table_b_ColumnName
,a.ORDINAL_POSITION,b.ORDINAL_POSITION as Table_b_Ordinal from table_a a full join Table_B b  on a.Table_aColumnName = b.Table_bColumnName
)

select * into #temp from preresult

SET @SQLList = (
select distinct display = STUFF((select  ','+table_a_columnName from  #temp b  order by table_b_ordinal FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') from #temp a
)


SET @SQLList2 = (
select distinct display = STUFF((select  ','+table_b_columnName from  #temp b  order by Table_b_Ordinal FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') from #temp a
)

SET @SQL = 'select ' +@SQLList +' from dbo.Table_a union all select ' + @SQLList2 + ' from dbo.table_b'
exec(@SQL)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: The result is what I want. I understood you approach. I should be able to translate it into my C# app. Thank you, plaidDK!